# Explanation sought: the ending of "The Web of the Magi"

Tags: novella

Just read Richard Cowper's *The Web of the Magi*. It was going along as a well-written if somewhat bog-standard Victorian-traveler-stumbles-into-magical-lost-civilization story right up until the last 20 pages.

Can someone please explain what happened here?

> The protagonist is trapped in a tiny spherical bottle universe?
>  The protagonist gets sucked into the loom's fabric and turns into a monkey?
>  Significance of the unfinished "comic strip"?